# "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed" при вызове file_get_contents к VK

Tags: php

Делаю запрос к Vkontakte, а тут такое. Получаю ошибку:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/access_token?client_id=3123913&client_secret=s67GdF41nhm2e44uEasSE&code=7b21a40b91f69f4ec2): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in C:...models\Vk.php on line 18

На локалхосте работало, при переносе на сервер - перестало. Думаю, дело где-то в конфиге. В конфиге php вроде все включено:

```
allow_url_fopen=On
allow_url_include=Off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сервере запрещено и правильно, я где-то читал про это, говорят, что большая дырка с этой функцией.

Comment: Я пытался через curl, он тоже возвращает false

Comment: Вообще подключение к другому серверу и загрузки на свой сервер тот контент - закрыт. Как открыть точно не могу подсказать, но как часто через эти функции забрасываю php файлик и потом делает что хочет =)

Comment: он как-то по кривому закрыт :) через тот же vkontakte.ru запрос проходит, а на https://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/access_token - нет.

Comment: А, возможно я ошибся насчет закрытия (п.с у меня на хосте по любой ссылки выдаст false))). Ваш сервер выходит наверно через прокси, вот через прокси попробуйте закрыть на https, кроме браузера ИЕ)